# i am getting error in console can not read property tostring() in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am getting error cannot read tostring() . below is my code please help on this

```
 function convertRounding(nValue) {

        var sArr = nValue.toString("0.00000").split('.');
        **var sVal = sArr[1].toString();**
        if (sVal == "00000" || sVal.substring(1) == "0000" || sVal.substring(2) == "000")
            return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(2);
        else if (sVal.substring(3) == "00")
            return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(3);
        else if (sVal.substring(4) == "0")
            return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(4);
        else
            return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(5);
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `convertRounding` ? What is the value getting passed ? and `.toString("0.00000")` will give you `RangeError` with the radix argument if the passed parameter is number

Comment: **var sVal = sArr[1].toString();** this piece of code give me error

Comment: And what is the value you are passing to `convertRounding` ? Are you passing a string value ?

Comment: i am passing floating value

Comment: Can you post the code ? Because JavaScript has no difference like INTEGER, FLOATS. All are **numbers**. I think you are passing as string.

**convertRounding(20.3333) is different from convertRounding("20.3333")**

Comment: convertRounding(parseFloat(parseFloat(gvPartList.rows[taxRowIndex].cells[Number(enmPartList.nUnitRate)].children[0].value) * parseFloat(nTaxAmt) / 100).toFixed(5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are passing in (nValue) doesn't contain a dot, and therefore will fail when you try to split.

Make sure your input can indeed be split first.

```
function convertRounding(nValue) {

    var sArr = nValue.toString().split('.');
    var sVal = sArr[1].toString();
    if (sVal == "00000" || sVal.substring(1) == "0000" || sVal.substring(2) == "000")
        return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(2);
    else if (sVal.substring(3) == "00")
        return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(3);
    else if (sVal.substring(4) == "0")
        return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(4);
    else
        return parseFloat(nValue).toFixed(5);
}

console.log(convertRounding(100.20));
//console.log(convertRounding(100)); // fails
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qgafbvot/2/

Updated to work with number input.

Comment: give me solution if i am passing string

Comment: updated to pass number.  The issue is your input cannot be 'split' because it doesn't contain a dot.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with radix nValue.toString(**"0.00000"**)
just try *nValue.toString()* this

Comment: **var sVal = sArr[1].toString();** this piece of code give me error